# Exposing VSTO code to VBA: Missing Reference

Tags: .net, vba, vsto

I have a document-level VSTO Add-In that is working fine. However, a user wanted to be able to call my .NET functions from VBA, so I followed the simple [MSDN procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157883.aspx) to "expose a host item to VBA'.

It works fine on my machine, but users get a MISSING reference in VBA for my .NET dll. VBA is looking for the dll in the source folder on my development machine (`C:\Source\...`), not in the install folder on their machine (`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\assembly\...`).

[image]

I'm using the standard ClickOnce deployment built in to Studio 2010.

My temporary solution is to provide a "Get .NET Dll" button in my Add-In that shows them the path to the dll using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. They manually update the reference in VBA using that value.

How do I correct this deployment issue?

Comment: Have you tried installing the DLL to the GAC? (Just a thought. I have no experience with this feature of VSTO.)

Comment: @nunzabar - i would strongly recommend to read this: [How to: Install a ClickOnce Office Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608592%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and this: [Walkthrough: Copying a Document to the End User Computer after a ClickOnce Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465291%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)